# in statement only working once for a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a simple text based hangman game, and I want to check if an user-inputted letter is part of a list containing the characters for the word that the user is supposed to guess.

Here is that part of the code:

```
while True:
print "Guess a letter / The word (%d attempts remaining.)" % attempts
guess = raw_input()
if len(guess) == 1:
    if guess in chars:
        blankslist[chars.index(guess) * 2] = guess
        blanks = "".join(str(x) for x in blankslist)
        print blanks
    else:
        print "Nope!"
        attempts -= 1
        if attempts <= 0:
            print "Game Over! The word was %s" % chosen_word
            break

elif len(guess) == len(chosen_word):
    if guess == chosen_word:
        print "Congrats, you won with %d attempts left!" % attempts
    else:
        print 'Oh no, you lost... The correct word was "%s".' % chosen_word
    break

else:
    print("Input a single letter")
```

However, for words that contain duplicate letters, such as "hippopotamus", it will only detect one "p". How can I make it detect both?

EDIT: Added whole loop for someone who asked.

Comment: can you add for loop in the code, how to guess and chars get modified after each loop

Comment: `.index(guess)` returns the first index of that value, just loop through the list and replace all occurences.

Comment: why is `blankslist` twice as long as `chars`?

Comment: that's because since my blankslist is something like _ _ _ _ _ and not _____ (for the user to understand how many letters the word has) I have to multiply the index by 2 so that it only replaces the underlines and not the empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`.index(guess)` only returns the first index it finds.

You could use something like this to get all indices:

```
positions = [i for i, char in enumerate(chars) if guess == char]
```

and then loop through this list:

```
for p in positions:
    blankslist[p * 2] = guess
```

Comment: It worked, but could you explain to me what the first line of code you added does? As a beginner I can't quite understand it.

Comment: @J.C. useful resource to understand list comprehension: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ also `help(enumerate)` will explain that part

Comment: @J.C. enumerate turns each element of the list to a tuple with zeroth element `i` being the index, and the first element `char` being the original element. You can rewrite it without a list comprehension as `positions = []` / `for i, char in enumerate(chars):` / `if guess == char:` / `positions.append(i)`